# Ruby on Rails - Restrict geocoder response to city and get the ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, geocoding, geocode, rails-geocoder

I have a Ruby on Rails project with the `users` table and I need to store the `location_id` from the user input.

- If user types `Buckingham Palace` then the location_id should be the `london_id`
- If user types `Wall Street` then the location_id should be the `new_york_id`
- If user types `Statue of Liberty` then the location_id should be the `new_york_id`
- If user types `United States` then the location_id should be `nil`

I am using `geocoder` gem, but I'm failing retrieving the city ID. For instance:

```
Geocoder.search("London").first.place_id # => ChIJdd4hrwug2EcRmSrV3Vo6llI
Geocoder.search("Buckingham Palace").first.place_id # => ChIJtV5bzSAFdkgRpwLZFPWrJgo
```

I need both to be `ChIJdd4hrwug2EcRmSrV3Vo6llI` (the London ID)

Comment: are you using geocoder gem?

Comment: Yes, as described in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my updated answer. It is integrated in Geocoder structure, and only needs one search if the query is a city name :

```
require 'geocoder'

module Geocoder
  # Returns the Google ID of the city containing the queried location. Returns nil if nothing found or if location contains multiple cities.
  def self.get_city_id(query, options={})
    results = search(query, options)
    unless results.empty?
      result = results.first
      city = result.city
      if city then
        if city == query then
          result.place_id
        else
          sleep(1)
          search(city,options).first.place_id
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

Geocoder::Configuration.timeout = 15

["London", "Buckingham Palace", "Wall Street", "Statue of Liberty Monument", "United States", "WEIRDqueryWithNoResult"].each{|query|
  puts query
  puts Geocoder.get_city_id(query).inspect
  sleep(1)
}
```

It outputs :

```
London
"ChIJdd4hrwug2EcRmSrV3Vo6llI"
Buckingham Palace
"ChIJdd4hrwug2EcRmSrV3Vo6llI"
Wall Street
"ChIJOwg_06VPwokRYv534QaPC8g"
Statue of Liberty Monument
"ChIJOwg_06VPwokRYv534QaPC8g"
United States
nil
WEIRDqueryWithNoResult
nil
```

For documentation purpose, here is my original answer:

```
require 'geocoder'


def get_city(search_term)
  Geocoder.search(search_term).first.city
end

def get_place_id(search_term)
  Geocoder.search(search_term).first.place_id
end

["London", "Buckingham Palace", "Wall Street", "Statue of Liberty Monument", "United States"].each{|term|
  puts (city=get_city(term)) && sleep(1) && get_place_id(city)
  sleep(1)
}
```

Comment: I think that you will have to add bounds params to the search to be more precise. Think of the edge case for cities like Berlin and Paris (Paris, France; Paris, TX, USA / Berlin, Germany; Berlin, MD, USA; Berlin, CT, USA) (e.g. from the readme `Geocoder.search("Paris", :bounds => [[32.1,-95.9], [33.9,-94.3]])`) https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder. You can approximate the bounds from the latitude/longitude given in the first search result.

Comment: True. But the uncertainty also comes from the first search :
`Geocoder.search('Statue of liberty').first.city` returns "Sandpoint"
It might not make sense to try to get a more accurate second search when the first one could be already completely wrong.

Comment: That's true. Might require some user confirmation.

Comment: This will work, though I was looking for a built-in or single step function. Thanks